# How to count the page visitors totals

Tags: php

**Fantastic day guys,**
Here is the my script to `count` the visitors who are visit the site and the `total` value is store in `txt` file. The Count is working.But when run this script, i am getting two `notice` errors.

> Notice: Use of undefined constant r - assumed 'r'
>
> Notice: Use of undefined constant w - assumed 'w'

**script**

```
if(file_exists('count_file.txt'))
{
    $fil = fopen('count_file.txt', r);
    $dat = fread($fil, filesize('count_file.txt'));
    echo $dat+1;
    fclose($fil);
    $fil = fopen('count_file.txt', w);
    fwrite($fil, $dat+1);
}
else
{
    $fil = fopen('count_file.txt', w);
    fwrite($fil, 1);
    echo '1';
    fclose($fil);
}
```

Comment: Wrap `r`, `w` in `"r"`, `"w"`.. more information: http://php.net/manual/bg/function.fopen.php

Comment: fopen('count_file.txt', 'r') and fopen('count_file.txt', 'w'). You forgot the quotes.

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter to `fopen()` is expected to be a string, so you're missing the quotes around `r` and `w`, since you're using both as if they were constants.

Answer (score 1):

you have to use strings, not constants. `'r'` instead of `r`